Flutter / Gradle build issues
Recently tried adding some firebase functionalities to my flutter app, which required me to get my hands a bit dirty in the Gradle files. At some point, the Gradle build stopped working completely. My attempts to fix the problems have only gotten me into more trouble. I'm barely functional at Flutter, but Gradle is a complete mystery to me. So much so that even the error messages I'm getting don't really make sense to me.
Context:

Android Studio: 2024.1.2
Flutter: 3.24.2
Dart: 3.5.2
DevTools: 2.37.2
Gradle: 8.9

android/build.gradle:
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        // [required] background_fetch
//        maven { url "${project(':background_fetch').projectDir}/libs" }
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
//
ext {
    compileSdkVersion   = 34
    targetSdkVersion    = 34
    appCompatVersion    = "1.4.2"
}

app/build.gradle:
plugins {
    id "com.android.application"
    id "kotlin-android"
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
    id "com.google.gms.google-services"
}

def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

//def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
//if (flutterRoot == null) {
//    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
//}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

//apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
//apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
//apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
    keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 34
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion
//    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.DOMAIN.APP"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 34
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
//        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
            keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
            storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
            storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }

}



flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:21.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:20.0.0'
}

assembleDebug error:
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/Users/drewmoe/Projects/APP/android/build.gradle' line: 15

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.
> A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
   > Could not create task ':app:copyFlutterAssetsDebug'.
      > Could not create task ':app:mergeDebugAssets'.
         > Cannot use @TaskAction annotation on method IncrementalTask.taskAction$gradle_core() because interface org.gradle.api.tasks.incremental.IncrementalTaskInputs is not a valid parameter to an action method.

I'm assuming my gradle code is an absolute nightmare of bad practices: I've tried to avoid touching it since I'm so in the dark, and only been able to move ahead in developing by trial/error.
Any ideas what the problem might be? I am completely at a loss. No idea what IncrementalTask.taskAction even refers to? I was making some pretty killer progress on my app until this just totally shut me down.

For me upgrading com.android.application version in settings.gradle file from 7.2.2 to 7.3.0 solved the issue.

Tested and works also with currently latest stable 8.7.1 version.
